# Regex for separating usernames in tags and commas

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following string:

```
@user1, @username2,@another.username
```

Note that there may or may not be a space after the commas, but there should always be a `@` before the start of the username.  I'm trying to create a regex to return me the following array of matches:

```
["user1","username2","another.username"]
```

I can't seem to come up with a non-greedy solution since my regex always stops after the first occurrence. How can I generate a regex to find all matching occurrences?

Comment: The regex should only match one occurrence. Then you tell your programming language to return an array of all the matches. What language are you using?

Comment: Ah- okay! I'm new to regex, so didn't know that!  I'm using javascript, so I can just run it multiple times until I don't get any more matches

Comment: Add the `g` flag to the regexp and it will return all the matches.

Comment: Why not just a split(',') method and remove '@' on each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex `/@[^,]+/g`
Note the `[^,]` for matching any character except a comma and the `g` for matching every occurence

Example use:

```js
let names = string.match(/@[^,]+/g)
//["@user1","@username2","@another.username"]

//Another option that uses split
let names = string.split(/, ?/g)

//If you want to remove the @
for(let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  names[i] = names[i].replace('@', '')
}
```